VSCode Markdown: Adding fenced code block highlight
I am trying to understand how to add a new color highlight for fenced code blocks in the markdown preview within VSCode, but I am lost. After spending hours reading various documents online I have not really made much progress.
What I gathered so far:

There are javascripts that define the highlight grammar, see here, for example;
It seems there is an option one could add to the settings.json as suggested here:
    "contributes": {
        "markdown.previewScripts": [
       "./main.js"
     ]
    }


Suggestions of using Markdown Preview and Markdown Preview Enhanced.
I tried to install the extension as mentioned in this post. There are no settings associated to this extension, so it seems there is not much one can do besides hoping it works.

However, I have not been able to find a way to add a new fenced code block highlight.  As the language  highlight is shown correctly in the raw .md document, it is really me not being able to configure the VSCode preview engine correctly.
Any suggestions/references you could provide?

Based on the default VS Code Markdown extension source code, you might provide your own CSS styles to fine tune the preview effect, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.88.1/extensions/markdown-language-features/package.json#L317 which should also include fenced code blocks. You will have to dig further into the generated HTML page for your .md file so as to learn which styles you should override.

@LexLi I looked at the extension settings, but there does not seem to be a way to change the way the fenced code block should be rendered in the preview via CSS. As mentioned in the post this goes via highlight.js, but I am not sure how to change/include the relevant one.

It appears from this post that in general there is not a good way to add a new language highlight even with the highlight.js (with the grammar). The post reproduces a similar situations as I see in my case (in the "raw" markdown the highlight are shown, but not in the preview).
